# Settings API no update status? (refering to the yellow bar when you save settings)

Tags: options

I just created some settings for my theme ... not perfect, still learning ...

http://pastie.org/1988772

I am expecting the "Settings Saved" yellow box

[image]

Do I need to do something on my part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this beneath the title should do it:

```
<?php settings_errors(); ?>
```

WordPress does this for you automatically on the 'options' pages, but you have to do it yourself in other sections of the site.